# XPath select one type of nodes only in direct child nodes

Tags: xpath

Maybe someone can help me find a solution to my problem.
I need to perform an XPath query in the xml below that pulls only the "Field" nodes that are direct child nodes.
In the below example, the query should pull fields E1F1, E1F2 and E1F3.
So far I am running the query: `//Field`, but I get all fields (including the ones that belong to E1_1 which I don't want).

```
<Entity id="E1">
  <Field id="E1F1"></Field>
  <Field id="E1F2"></Field>
  <Field id="E1F3"></Field>
  <Entity id="E1_1">
    <Field id="E1_1F1"></Field>
    <Field id="E1_1F2"></Field>
    <Field id="E1_1F3"></Field>
  </Entity>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use an absolute XPath:

```
/Entity/Field
```

`//` will match anywhere. If you use a single forwardslash, the match must be exact.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the wanted node is far from the root element(the /html), so the accepted answer is not what I needed, after some search work, I find the `child` [axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp) instead of `descendant`, I hope this may help someone who is use `scrapy` to get some info from html.

Comment: The axes link is broken unfortunately. maybe it was https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp