# Select descendant elements that are not contained in another type of element

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

In XPath 1.0, how can I select all descendant nodes C of current (context) node A, that are not contained in an intervening node of type B?

For example, find all `<a>` links contained in the current element, that are not inside a `<p>`. But if the current element is itself inside a `<p>`, that's irrelevant.

```
<p>                   <—— this is irrelevant, because it's outside the current element
    ...
    <div>             <—— current element (context node)
        ...
        <a></a>       <—— the xpath should select this node
        ...
        <p>
            ...
            <a></a>   <—— but not this, because it's inside a p, which is inside context
            ...
        <p>
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</p>
```

The `...` in the example could be several depths of intervening nodes.

I'm writing XSLT 1.0, so the additional functions `generate-id()`, `current()`, and such are available.

Comment: Something like `/p/div/a` ? And this is duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818191/xpath-select-one-type-of-nodes-only-in-direct-child-nodes

Comment: @fukanchik no, I'm already in the `div` (current context node) and I need to select all `a` that are not inside a `p`, possibly with several middle nodes in between, for example several levels of `div` in between.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one possible XPath :

```
.//a[not(ancestor::p/ancestor::* = current())]
```

This XPath checks if current descendant `a` element doesn't have ancestor `p` which ancestor is current context node. In other words, it checks if the `a` element doesn't have ancestor `p` intervening between the `a` and the current context node.

Comment: That makes sense, but is the `=` doing the right thing there? Don't I need something like `.//a[not(ancestor::p/ancestor::*[generate-id(.) = generate-id(current())])]` ?

Comment: @Tobia Sorry, I'm not sure my self if the expression will compare the element's value or compare the elements by reference (which I hope it to do)

Comment: I don't think it's right, because "If both objects to be compared are node-sets, then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the first node-set and a node in the second node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the **string-values** of the two nodes is true." [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans)

Comment: Still, either your expression or my `generate-id()` variant will do. Thanks!

Comment: why start with .// rather than // ?